# Get array from json in android

Tags: java, android, json

```
{
    "issueName": "2013-11-12",
    "direction": "rtl",
    "timestamp": "1384184763",
    "download": {
        "preview": "preview.zip",
        "content": {
            "count": 9,
            "files": ["1.zip",
            "2.zip",
            "3.zip",
            "4.zip",
            "5.zip",
            "6.zip",
            "7.zip",
            "8.zip",
            "9.zip"]
        },
        "thumbnail": "thumbnail.zip",
        "advertorial": "advertorial.zip"
    },
    "pages": {
        "1": {
            "pageNo": "1",
            "files": ["Pg001.png",
            "Web201311_P1_medium.jpg",
            "Pg001_142_p.jpg",
            "Pg001_142_t.png",
            "Pg001_142_p_ios.jpg",
            "Pg001_142_t_ios.png"],
            "section": 0
        },
        "2": {
            "pageNo": "2",
            **"files"**: ["Pg002.png",
            "Web201311_P2_medium.jpg",
            "Pg002_142_p.jpg",
            "Pg002_142_t.png",
            "Pg002_142_p_ios.jpg",
            "Pg002_142_t_ios.png"],
            "section": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to get **"pages"=>"files"**, but return `org.json.JSONException: No value for files`

```
JSONObject issueInfo = new JSONObject(filePath));
JSONObject pages = issueInfo.getJSONObject("pages");
Iterator iterator = pages.keys();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    JSONObject page = pages.getJSONObject(key);
    JSONArray files = pages.getJSONArray("files");
    String _thumbUri = files.getString(1);
    String _graphicUri = files.getString(2);
    String _textUri = files.getString(3);
}
```

Comment: thanks for attention, it seems some syntax error only

Comment: `JSONArray files = page.getJSONArray("files");` here, use `page` instead of `pages`.

Comment: probably some objects not contains `files` JSONArray so either use `optJSONArray` to get JSONArray which return `null` if key not found or use `JSONObject.has`JSONObject.isNull` before accessing values from `files` JSONArray

Comment: Typo in your code. Beware of the variables' name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of getting `files JSONArray` from **page** `JSONObject` you are trying to get it from **pages** `JSONObject`.. Try this:

```
JSONObject issueInfo = new JSONObject(filePath));
JSONObject pages = issueInfo.getJSONObject("pages");
Iterator iterator = pages.keys();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    JSONObject page = pages.getJSONObject(key);
    JSONArray files = page.getJSONArray("files");  //Correction here
    String _thumbUri = files.getString(1);
    String _graphicUri = files.getString(2);
    String _textUri = files.getString(3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mistake:**

You are trying to get `files` from `pages` object instead of `page` object.

```
JSONArray files = pages.getJSONArray("files");
```

**Solution:**

```
JSONArray files = page.getJSONArray("files");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray files = pages.getJSONArray("files");
```

Since files is not the direct child of the root `JSONObject use the below method.

```
JSONObject page = pages.getJSONObject(key).getJSONArray("files");
```